Unable to disable POST methods in Springdoc swagger UI
I am using springdoc UI to generate the documentation of my Java API and want to disable the try it out button (which should actually be the default behavior according to the docs)
I have tried both:

springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled=false
springdoc.swagger-ui.supportedSubmitMethods=

Neither of them seem to have any impact.
I am using spring-boot 3.2.x and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.6.0.

try downgrading swagger ui version.

Thank you. You have pointed both Mario and myself in the right direction and I was able to solve my issues based on both your answers.

@kush parsaniya's comment seems to be right. There is a problem with version 2.6.0 of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui. The issue has also been reported a few months ago. Take a look over here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2740.
Please do not downgrade to an older version, as it might pose vulnerabilities. I tried to upgrade to 2.7.0 (latest stable version), and it seems to be working properly.

I eventually ended up downgrading after all since Maven kept saying the POM of 2.7.0 was invalid. I am not sure why I'm getting this issue, but downgrading helped solve my main issue so you were right that there indeed was a problem version 2.6.0.

@Cami should definitely work. The version is listed inside the Maven Repo. I also tested it myself. Probably you missed clicking the "update" button inside IntelliJ (or the IDE you're using)
